# Using the geo index, how can I find the closest item in cache.

Tags: caching, gridgain

What are the different kinds of geo spatial queries we can run against items in cache? To start, I need to find the closest item in cache to a given Point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo!

GridGain (as well as H2 database does) supports operator && in SQL which means "intersection of bounding boxes". This operator is rather primitive but it can use geospatial indexes to work fast,
so that any complex subsequent filtering can be done on a minor subset of entries.

As a reference you can use the following [unit test](https://github.com/gridgain/gridgain/blob/23010d33bcb98a5dbd93b896ac0a7bf4004e4ab7/modules/indexing/src/test/java/org/gridgain/grid/spi/indexing/h2/GridH2IndexingSpiGeoSelfTest.java).

In that unit test you will see the following entity:

```
private static class EnemyCamp implements Serializable {
    /** */
    @GridCacheQuerySqlField(index = true)
    private Geometry coords;

    /** */
    @GridCacheQuerySqlField
    private String name;
}
```

which is indexed by field "coords" of type com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry. We can put a number of such entities to a cache and query a list of entries whose coords (coords here is a point and thus it's bounding box is the same point) has intersection with bounding box of the given polygon.

```
GridCache<Integer, EnemyCamp> cache = ...;

WKTReader r = new WKTReader();

cache.put(0, new EnemyCamp(r.read("POINT(25 75)"), "A"));
cache.put(1, new EnemyCamp(r.read("POINT(70 70)"), "B"));
cache.put(2, new EnemyCamp(r.read("POINT(70 30)"), "C"));
cache.put(3, new EnemyCamp(r.read("POINT(75 25)"), "D"));

GridCacheQuery<Map.Entry<Integer, EnemyCamp>> qry = cache.queries().createSqlQuery(EnemyCamp.class,
    "coords && ?");

Collection<Map.Entry<Integer, EnemyCamp>> res = qry.execute(r.read("POLYGON((5 70, 5 80, 30 80, 30 70, 5 70))")).get();
```

After we have result returned by this query we can filter it further in java code for example using method Geometry.isWithinDistance

Have fun!

Comment: Thank you for the answer, very useful. To make sure I understand. The && operator is the only geo spatial operator that is supported in grid gain? And to find the closest city to a point, without a larger bounding box, I should pull out the complete list of cities and use the Geometry library?  I might have to revert back to a db for this lookup.

Comment: Holy crap! I a bit missed initial question about finding the closest entity to some given point. Of course there is no need to pull complete list of entries, since GridGain is all about moving computation to data but not data to computation :) You can solve this by adding remote reducer to the SQL query, which will collect on remote node only results that met your criteria. I would still recommend to have some sane bounds around your search point to avoid processing the whole dataset on each query.

Comment: As for && operator, it is actually the only way to use geospatial indexes. If you don't need to or can't use indexes you can use just [scan queries](http://gridgain.com/sdk/6.5.0/javadoc/org/gridgain/grid/cache/query/GridCacheQueries.html#createScanQuery%28org.gridgain.grid.lang.GridBiPredicate%29) which will do full cache scan with filtering on remote nodes.

Comment: I forgot about the scan query, that makes sense. Thanks!